# Improvement requests not showing in documentation dashboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I've noticed the C# documentation dashboard is empty almost *every time* I look at it - particularly the 'Requested Topics' and 'Need Improvement' fields.

However, today I accidentally stumbled across an improvement request:

---

[image]

---

And yet on the dashboard, no requests are visible:

---

[image]

---

Nor when checking the 'need improvement' tab:

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the day, we intended for "other" improvement requests to be moderator-only. Then we didn't actually implement them that way (or I broke it some months ago... either is possible). With the benefit of hindsight, I don't think it's necessary to stick to the original intent there, so starting with the next build "other" improvement requests will no longer be filtered out of the tag dashboards.